# Restricting overflow outside top of the browser

Tags: css, html

I have to restrict horizontal scrolling and vertical scrolling. One of the option to restrict overflow in HTML is to have css property `overflow:hidden (overflow-x:hidden or overflow-y:hidden)` I am able to prevent horizontal scrolling using `overflow-x:hidden`.

I am allowed to have vertical scrolling (using `overflow-y:auto`) only when element is dragged towards the bottom of the screen but not allowed to cross top of the screen.

Comment: please provide a jsfiddle. also try `overflow-y: scroll;`

Comment: So are you asking how to disable scrolling and enable it only if an element is dragged to the bottom? ..When scrolling is disabled, is there any (invisible) content outside the window? When you scroll when dragging the element, what content should show up at the bottom? Wouldn't be easier to make the page 100% x 100% of the window and when dragged, dynamically extend the height of the page?